# A simple way to make one stream line in StreamPlot thicker, or change its color?

Tags: plotting, graphics

[Simple way to highlight streams in basins of attraction in StreamDensityPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188622/simple-way-to-highlight-streams-in-basins-of-attraction-in-streamdensityplot)   gives a beautiful way for coloring differently the manifolds of a phase-plot, i.e. `StreamPlot`.

That rather sophisticated code could be adapted, but what I need is possibly simpler. Sticking to the same example

```
plot = StreamDensityPlot[{{3 x^2 - 6 y, 3 y^2 - 6 x}}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 
    0, 3}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[{2, 2}], Green, 
     Point[{0.7252, 1.113}]}];
lin = Line[{{0, 1}, {3, 1.44}}];
Show[{plot}, Graphics[lin]]
```

I would like to color in different colors, or just thicken the path from red point to green point, and out of the green point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, find the curve {x[t],y[t]}:

```
{xsol, ysol} = 
 NDSolveValue[{3 x[t]^2 - 6 y[t] == -D[x[t], t], 
   3 y[t]^2 - 6 x[t] == - D[y[t], t], x[0] == 0.7252, 
   y[0] == 1.113 }, {x, y}, {t, -1, 1}]
```

The numerical solution has difficulty near the saddle as expected.
Nevertheless,

```
plot = StreamDensityPlot[{{3 x^2 - 6 y, 3 y^2 - 6 x}}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 
    0, 3}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[{2, 2}], Green, 
     Point[{0.7252, 1.113}]}];
pplot = ParametricPlot[{xsol[t], ysol[t]}, {t, -0.3292115680646588`, 
   1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.005]}]
lin = Line[{{0, 1}, {3, 1.44}}];
Show[{plot, pplot, Graphics[lin]}]
```

[image]